# How to remove 'error' class from form field?

Tags: forms, theming

I need to remove the error class from field after form submit. How to do that?

I found the function called _form_set_class but I suppose I can't overwrite it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`_form_set_class()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21form.inc/function/calls/_form_set_class/7) is called from a bunch of different theme functions, including

- [`theme_checkbox()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21form.inc/function/theme_checkbox/7)
- [`theme_fieldset()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21form.inc/function/theme_fieldset/7)
- [`theme_file()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21form.inc/function/theme_file/7)

(the rest are [here](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21form.inc/function/calls/_form_set_class/7))

You can override whichever of those functions you need to in your theme by renaming the function as (e.g.)

```
function MYTHEME_checkbox($vars) {
```

Then copy in the original code from the function, remove the call to `_form_get_class()`, and replace it with whatever makes sense for your use case.